# Use of Present simple tense (You stroll in...)

Tags: tenses, present-tense

It's from the movie "The Mask"

Situation: Someone has robbed the bank where Stanley Ipkiss works.

Stanley's boss reprimands Stanley for being late: We have a crisis here, and you **stroll in** an hour late?

I would have said that sentence either in Present continuous or in Present Perfect.

Self-made: We have a crisis here, and you are strolling/have strolled in an hour late?

I've read in one of my grammar books that sometimes we use Present Simple in narratives and anecdotes to highlight an event.

1. Is that the reason the speaker used Present Simple instead of Present Perfect/Present Continuous in the original sentence?
2. Will it be incorrect if I say that sentence in Present Perfect or Present Continuous?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a stressed usage. 'We have a crisis here, and you are strolling in an hour late?' and  'We have a crisis here, and you have strolled in an hour late?' sound silly, weak – but 'We have a crisis here, and you come strolling in an hour late?' is punchy enough to work.

Comment: Could someone give me more examples where Simple Present is used in the same way?